# Haskell zip lists to lists of tulples

Tags: haskell

```
>cprod [1,2,3] [’a’, ’b’]
[(1,’a’),(2,’a’),(3,’a’),(1,’b’),(2,’b’),(3,’b’)]
```

I try to implement the code by using zip but I know it is not enough. I also tried to use map but I just don't know how to start. Any tips or little help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehension is another way to do this.

```
[(x, y) | y <- ['a', 'b'], x <- [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a use case for the `[]` monad (more specifically, the `[]` applicative functor). `[]` (as an applicative functor) encapsulates the idea of "try every possible combination of these things", i.e. a generalized Cartesian product.

```
flip (,) <$> ['a', 'b'] <*> [1, 2, 3]
```

If you don't care about the order, then you needn't worry about flipping

```
(,) <$> [1, 2, 3] <*> ['a', 'b']
```

Generally, `zip` (and the `ZipList` applicative functor) will join lists pairwise, so the first element matches the first, the second the second, and so on. The `[]` applicative functor will perform the Cartesian product, which is what you're looking for.